# Is there a tool that finds strings in XAML to localize?

Tags: c#, localization

I am needing to localize an existing app written in C# with WPF/XAML.  I have found the Rgreatex plugin to Resharper that helps find and move strings found in C# to resource files.  But, it only works with *.cs files.  Does anyone know of a tool that helps find localizable strings in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't use the LocBaml tool since management believes it to be very beta.  I have been unable to find anything else to do this so I guess I'll writer my own utility similar to the Resharper plugin but for XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LocBaml tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771568.aspx) to do much of this.  I'd recommend reading the [WPF Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx#workflow_to_localize) section on MSDN, since this is usually done a bit differently in WPF than it was in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is pretty late but [Soluling](https://www.soluling.com/) can localize [XAML files and WPF applications](https://www.soluling.com/Help/WPF/Index.htm). It uses [scan rules](https://www.soluling.com/Help/ScanRules.htm) to identify what elements in the XAML files are extracted, provides an UI to translate them and finally creates the localized XAML files. Soluling goes even further and compiles the localized XAML files into binary format (BAML) and then creates localized satellite assemblys files that contain the localized XAML, ResX and other resources.

You don't have to specify every XAML file but only the project file(s) (.csproj/.vbproj) or the solution file (.sln),